# Azure ML - Install GitHub package in environment

Tags: python, docker, environment, azure-machine-learning-service, git-clone

I am new to Azure ML and creating my own Python environment.

I am trying to use Azure ML to run my detectron2 (instance segmentation) code. For this, I need to install their detectron2 package from GitHub. I based my code on a [Google Colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16jcaJoc6bCFAQ96jDe2HwtXj7BMD_-m5#scrollTo=h9tECBQCvMv3) given by the Facebook research team. Here, in the notebook, we simply do:

```
!git clone 'https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2'
dist = distutils.core.run_setup("./detectron2/setup.py")
!python -m pip install {' '.join([f"'{x}'" for x in dist.install_requires])}
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('./detectron2'))
```

or

```
!python -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'
```

and then

```
import detectron2
```

Now, I want to run my detectron2 code in AzureML. For this, I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-pytorch?view=azureml-api-2). I simply converted my .ipynb detectron2 file to .py, created a workspace, resource, used one of Azure's PyTorch curated environments and simply submitted the job. In the logs, I then understood that lines such as `!pip` or `!git` return syntax errors. Instead, I learned that one should create an environment that encompasses the required packages (?).

Now this I find difficult. Instead of using one of their curated environments, I created a new environment. In the context pane of each environment, the user can edit the Docker file and requirements. I tried several things. In the requirements, I listed every necessary package. Including `detectron2` or `git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git`. I tried editing the Docker file by using the [one](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile) provided by detectron2. I tried variations based on [detectron2 installation instructions](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html) (for example `RUN pip install git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git` within the Docker file).

However, I keep getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'detectron2.utils'; 'detectron2' is not a package` error in the Azure logs whenever I submit and run my code.

What is the correct way to install a GitHub package such as detectron2 in Azure ML? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom environment (you can also use CLI or SDK) as shown in following link (via GUI) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-azure-container-for-pytorch-environment?view=azureml-api-2

I added following to the dockerfile (other then using the curated environment `FROM` statement)

```
pip install azureml-mlflow
pip install torch
python -m pip install "git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git"
```

It takes a little while for the environment to get created - you should see build status as "Succeeded".
Once environment is build and ready - you should be able to use it in jobs/scripts as usual.
e.g.

```
from azureml.core.environment import CondaDependencies
mycustomenv = Environment(name="test-env-detectron")
.
.
.
# use variable mycustomenv as needed
```

Screen-shot from GUI showing environment built that I tried -
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this, and several variations. However, I am still running into this error: `No module named 'detectron2.utils'; 'detectron2' is not a package`. All other packages seem to work, it is the detectron2 package that it is unable to load for some reason.

Comment: I solved my problem. The reason I got this error was because my python script was also named `detectron2.py`. So when I did `import detectron2`, I really imported my python script (I assume). Now I have changed my name, I do not encounter this error anymore. So creating a custom environment (like you and I did) definitely is not the problem!